# Is Chrome responsible for my 100% disk usage?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, microsoft-edge, resource-usage

My computer, an ASUS M509DA laptop freezes every now and then. When I opened the task manager, I saw Chrome at the top of the list and disk usage as 100%:

[image: screenshot of task manager process list]

Does Google Chrome look like the only culprit here? As you can see in the picture, there are also lots of background processes running on my computer. Could they also be causing this issue?

Several commenters asked about RAM. The details of my computer are as follows:

Processor: AMD Ryzen 3 3250U with Radeon Graphics 2.60 Hz
Installed RAM: 8.00 GB (5.95 GB usable)

This is an ASUS VivoBook laptop and I am running Windows 11 on it.

I have even tried running Microsoft Edge instead of Google Chrome and every now and then, my computer still freezes. I got a screenshot of my task manager stats when that happens:

[image: screenshot of task manager RAM usage]

As you can see in the image, disk utilization is 100% and memory usage is also close to 100%. Windows scan of my hard-drive reported no errors.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146167/discussion-on-question-by-user1801482-is-chrome-responsible-for-my-100-disk-usa); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: It's on top due to the sort order you picked.

Comment: Use a good tab freezing extension to lower memory usage at least.

Comment: @Destroy666 I selected the option on MSFT Edge which puts tabs that have been inactive for a while to sleep. Do you think that is sufficient?

Comment: Could be, could be not. Depends on your usage. Extensions have usually more options than that.

Comment: The feature is typically called "lazy tab loading".

Comment: @Destroy666 _Extensions have usually more options than that._ Can't find any extensions for Edge...

Comment: Edge is Chromium-based, any Chrome extensions should work: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/add-turn-off-or-remove-extensions-in-microsoft-edge-9c0ec68c-2fbc-2f2c-9ff0-bdc76f46b026

Comment: @Destroy666 Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your system does not have enough RAM for your workload. ~6 GiB of usable memory is simply not enough for a Windows system today. You need at least 8 GiB. Depending on the tasks you perform (like audio/image/video editing) a lot more may be necessary. (The “missing” RAM in your case is reserved for the integrated GPU. It cannot work without a portion of your RAM.)

Chrome is not exactly memory-efficient. This means all other Chromium-based browsers, like Edge, aren’t either. There’s only really one alternative: Firefox. It uses *ever so slightly* less memory.

As your RAM fills up, the computer will move data from RAM to the disk to save memory (this is called [*paging*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_paging), and the file used on disk is the *page file*). Thus, actual usage of the page file starts to intensify. You can think of the page file as an extension to your physical memory, but located on your HDD/SSD. (In reality, it’s a lot more complicated.) The system has to use it when physical memory is largely filled. Here’s the next problem with your system: It still has an HDD. Usually, it’d just be a tad slow, but when loaded with lots of random access to the page file, your system will all but grind to a halt.

So there are two potential upgrades. Both would *tremendously* speed up your computer. Switching to a SSD should be relatively easy. Maybe the system even has a free M.2 slot, meaning you could keep the HDD for bulk storage. More precise information could be available with the *exact* model number. Upgrading RAM is less likely to be possible, because more and more laptops come with RAM soldered to the mainboard. However, if it fits an HDD, it could work. Again, better information might be available with the exact model number.

---

Unfortunately, what you provided is not the model number but something else. Check with the [guide on how to find the model number](https://www.asus.com/us/support/Article/565/) to get the right number (make sure to include the portion after the dash, it contains the specific configuration.)

However, going by the model family (X509/M509), ASUS offers [service manuals](https://www.asus.com/us/supportonly/m509da/helpdesk_service_guide/) with detailed instructions on how to change/upgrade the vital components: 2.5″ HDD/SSD, M.2 SSD, RAM.

This model series apparently comes with 4 GiB of soldered-on memory + 4 GiB of DDR4 PC4-19200 2400MHz Non-ECC SODIMM memory. The latter you can freely upgrade up to a total of 12 GiB (or 20 GiB, depending on who you ask).

Because this model series is also available with M.2 SSDs, you can install any NVMe M.2 2280 SSD, optionally while also keeping your hard drive. (I recommend removing it though: Using only SSDs will reduce risk to your data in case of fall damage etc.)

---

*Important:* Before proceeding with any upgrades, use the [guide on how to find the serial number](https://www.asus.com/us/support/Article/566/) and use that in [ASUS’ support portal](https://www.asus.com/us/support) to make sure these manuals apply to your device. Do not share your device’s serial number on Super User.

Comment: @DanielB _Using only SSDs will reduce risk to your data in case of fall damage etc._ Can you please explain what you mean by "fall damage" and under what circumstances can it happen?

Comment: When you drop your laptop.

Comment: Oh you meant that literally :D. So it is because HDD is bulkier and it's located in a more visible fashion..

Comment: No. A HDD contains mechanical components. An SSD, as the name suggests, does not.

Comment: Oh ok. I understand. Thank you